# Problem regarding open set/closed set

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ and $V$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$
. Define
$U + V = \{a + b | a ∈ U, b ∈ V\}.$

Then  which  of the  following statement is true ?

$1.$ if $U$  is an open set and if $V$ is a closed set, then $U + V$ is an open set;

$2.$ if $U$  is an open set and if $V$ is a closed set, then $U + V$ is an closed  set;

My attempt : if i take  $V =[0,1]$  , $U =  (0,1)$ , then $U +V = [0,1]$

then option $2)$  is true ?

Is its  true ?

Comment: I would try doing that sum of $U$ and $V$ again. Note that $2/3 \in U$ and $2/3 \in V$, so $4/3 = 2/3 + 2/3 \in U + V$, but $4/3 \notin [0, 1]$. It's usually a good idea to make an educated guess as to the value of $U + V$, but you should also formally prove it! Try proving $U + V = (0, 2)$ instead.

Comment: oh  . yaa   i missed that @TheoBendit

Comment: Think about $U+\{a\}$. Is that still open? And what relation is there between $U+\{a,b\}$, $U+\{a\}$, and $U+\{b\}$? Can you go from there?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  sir  thanks  for  hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$If $U,V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $U$ is open, then $U+V$ is open.

**Proof:**

Let $W=U+V$.

For each $b\in V$, let $W_b=U+\{b\}=\{a+b\mid a\in U\}$.

For each $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let $T_c$ be translation by $c$.

Explicitly, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $T_c(x)=x+c$.

It's easily verified that each $T_c$ is a homeomorphism.

Then for $b\in V$, we have $W_b=T_b(U)$, hence, since $T_b$ is a homeomorphism and $U$ is open, it follows that $W_b$ is open.

Clearly we have $W={\small{\displaystyle{\bigcup_{\large{{b\in V}}}}}} W_b$, hence, since each $W_b$ is open, it follows that $W$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

> Proposition: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $U$ is an open set and $V$ is a
>   closed set, then $U+V$ is an open set.

Proof: Note that for any point $z\in U+V$, there exist $x\in U$ and $y \in V$ such that $z=x+y$. Since $U$ is an open set, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist $x'\in U$ such that $d(x,x')<\epsilon$ and $x'\in U$. It is easy to see that

1. $z'=x'+y\in U+V$;
2. $d(z,z')=d(x,x')<\epsilon$.

So $U+V$ is an open set. QED.

Remark: The condition that $V$ is closed set, is not used. Thus we can say, an open set plus a set is an open set.